# how to sort nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following fields: etl time, business_date, name, code, money. I want to sort all the data according to the CODE field with the data type nvarchar (50) and sort in ascending order. The value of the CODE field before sorting is 1,2,3,10,21,22,31. The value of the CODE field after sorting is 1,10,2,21,22,3,31. But I can only arrange once. After deleting the old data and inserting it again a second time, the table does not sort in the correct order. How to reorder the value of CODE in the correct order after deleting the data and adding new again?

Comment: The only thing that sorts data in SQL is an `ORDER BY` clause. The order of rows as you insert them is functionally irrelevant. It sounds like what you really need here is an `INT` field you fill from your `NVARCHAR(50)` (possibly as a computed column) so you can sort on that.

Comment: i know but the customer asked me to sort nvarchar, ie in the order of 1,10,2,21,22,3,31. rather than in the order of integer (1,2,3,10,21,22,31). Do you have any way?

Comment: Then your question isn't clear, because `ORDER BY [Code]` should already do what you want -- when comparing strings, `'10' < '2'`.

Comment: but after deleting the data that was added to the table for the first time and this data has been sorted, when added a second time, the data is no longer sorted.

Comment: The data was never sorted to begin with. In SQL, a table is conceptually a *set* of rows. There is no "native" or "default" order -- there is an on-disk order of the rows, but this is not technically a sort order, and it is not necessarily what you get if you specify no `ORDER BY` (for example, the server may choose to run the query in parallel, which "messes up" the order). A query that wants to retrieve the rows "in sorted order" *must* specify an `ORDER BY`, every time. Otherwise the order of the rows you get back is unspecified.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY CAST(CODE AS int)` to your `SELECT` query to return rows in the desired order. Note that this will fail if the `CODE` column contains non-numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY CAST(code AS int);
```